# que archivos pasar a producción del la carpeta "bin/debug"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un proyecto Windows Forms. En el momento de compilar se generan 6 archivos (.exe, .exe.configm, .pdb, .vshost.exe, .vshost.exe.config, .vshost.exe.manifest).

De 6, sé para qué sirve el .exe y el .exe.config, pero los otros 4 no. ¿Para qué sirven esos otros? ¿Cuál de ellos debería desplegar?

Comment: y hacer un publish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No deberias pasar ningun archivo desde esa carpeta, para pasar a produccion deberias compilar en `Release`

Los archivos que tengan `vshost` o `pdb` son usados por el VS para debug, esos no debes copiarlos

el `.exe` y `.exe.config` si deberias llevarlos a la otra pc junto a  la dll que utilice

**>>en donde aparece la release?**

Para compilar en release puede cambiarlo aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o sino desde el `Configuration Manager`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero en la carpeta bin solo aparece la debug, en donde aparece la release? o como se la generá?. saludos

Comment: Nota, ese proyecto que estoy dando mantenimiento esta en vs2008, porque en vs2015 se que hay combo donde se selecciona debug release y otros, pero en vs2008 no encuentro donde seleccioanar release.

Comment: @RSillerico algunas versiones express solo tiene la opcion de debug, porque son gratuitas

Comment: no uses la version express del VS usa la community https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Comment: La la encontré Leandro, mil gracias, de todas maneras como comentario (ya entendí que solo el .exe y el .exe.config) en la carpeta release también se generó el archivo .pdb y .vshost.*** etc

Comment: El `.vshost` siempre va a ser generado, porque puedes depurar la aplicacion incluso cuando esta va a ser lanzada @RSillerico

Answer (score 4):

Según MSDN:

`.pdb`: Son archivos utilizados en la depuración (debug) de un programa, se generan con el proposito de proveer al desarrollador la información necesaria para poder depurar el ejecutable actual.

`.exe`: Es el ejecutable de tu aplicación.

`.exe.config`: Contiene las configuraciones actuales de tu aplicación para hacer la depuración, [una respuesta (En ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174232/5622844).

`.vshost.exe`: Son archivos que permiten a Visual Studio una depuración más rápida (Por así decirlo), no son más que un wrapper de VS.

`.vshost.config`: Contiene las configuraciones del host de Visual Studio.

`.vshost.exe.manifest`: Es el archivo de "manifiesto", contiene metadatos de aplicación, tales como: Version, Nombre del programa y demás propiedades de los ejecutables.

Para configurar Visual Studio en modo `Release`, la respuesta de [Leandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17364/4499) es la correcta, compila en `Release` usando el administrador de configuraciones.

[image: Configuración de Visual Studio]

En el `DropDownBox` que dice `Debug`, cambialo por `Release`, si tienes algúna plataforma designada, marcala en el cuadro que está a la derecha (Any CPU) y compila la solución.

Al finalizar el proceso de compilado, sacas en un directorio aparte los archivos de tu aplicación que iran a producción:

```
*.exe, *.exe.config
```

Y cualquier dll que use el proyecto *(Recuerda crear una copia local de estas, en las configuraciones de archivo de Visual Studio)*, al poner la configuración en `Release` Visual Studio crea la respectiva carpeta con los archivos necesarios.

[Cómo: Establecer configuraciones Debug y Release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wx0123s5.aspx)